# EntityNotFoundException when using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

On an application that I work on we have been having an issue coming through in our logs for quite some time now. We thought that we had fixed this recently but unfortunately it still persists and I have run out of ideas regarding how to fix it.

The problem is that when our users load a certain page we run a JPQL / HQL query in the background to retrieve the data necessary for display. For some reason this query complains about an EntityNotFoundException some times but not consistently. It seems to happen some times when a record was recently deleted from the table that we are querying. As far as I can tell, the issue seems to be that the deleted record is still in the L2 cache. The reason I believe this to be the case is because when this exception is being thrown it does not go away until I manually refresh the L2 cache.

The stack trace is below. In this example we have an Entity called "FeedPostTag" and there used to be a FeedPostTag with ID 18858 but then some user deleted that and then when anyone tries to reload their "feed" page which would've shown this FeedPostTag, we get the exception.

We even tried programmatically evicting this specific entity from the cache straight after we remove it but that didn't seem to work either.

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find
>   za.co.bsg.ems.server.model.entity.social.FeedPostTag with id 18858 at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:183)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
>   at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.assemble(ManyToOneType.java:282)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache.get(StandardQueryCache.java:204)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultFromQueryCache(Loader.java:2481)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listUsingQueryCache(Loader.java:2389)
>   at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2362) at
>   org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497) at
>   org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
>   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264) at
>   org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103) at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573) at
>   org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)

I'm not sure if this is just a bug in Hibernate or if we are actually doing something wrong in our application code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: please provide code of hibernate entity and configuration?

Comment: @Praful Makani that shouldn't really make a difference. In a nutshell, FeedPostTag is just a normal Entity with ManyToOne references to some other standard entities, e.g. FeedPost and Tag. As for the configuration, the only thing really worth noting there is that both L2 cache and query cache via EhCache have been enabled. Btw, this is just an example entity class that this happens, we have this same issue for other entities, not just FeedPostTag.

Comment: I am facing same problem May I ask you how did you fixed that problem?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've written, it seems you still have a reference to this record in your *database*. Note that this exception happens when assembling the results gathered from the query cache, so, something that has a `ManyToOne` relationship with `FeedPostTag` is trying to load the non-existing record. It's not about `FeedPostTag` being seen by Hibernate, it's about a different record having a relationship with this entity, which cannot be loaded by Hibernate once needed.

```
org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.assemble(ManyToOneType.java:282) at     
org.hibernate.cache.internal.StandardQueryCache.get(StandardQueryCache.java:204) at 
org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultFromQueryCache(Loader.java:2481) at
```

Note that the results from the query cache are loaded, and then the relationships are assembled, and finally the exception occurs. So, "something" that has a relationship to `FeedPostTag` was cached and retrieved.

In your database, go over the tables that have a reference to `FeedPostTag` and check which one has a reference to the non-existing record. Something like:

```
select id from Tag where FeedPostTag_id = 18858;
select id from Feed where FeedPostTag_id = 18858;
select id from Post where FeedPostTag_id = 18858;
```

Comment: thanks but I'm sure that the issue is not that there is something still referencing the deleted entity in the DB for 2 reasons: (1) a foreign key constraint would've failed and not allowed the deletion in the first place and...

Comment: (2) when I clear the cache manually this issue goes away. If the problem was an orphan reference in the database itself then clearing the cache would not fix the issue. I see that on our side when we manually clear the L2 cache that we also manually clear the query cache. The more I look at this the more I am sure it is either a bug in the query cache code or something I am doing wrong related to the query cache.